# Tensorflow 2.0 ValueError while Loading weights from .h5 file

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a VAE architecture script as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Conv2DTranspose, Lambda, Reshape, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

INPUT_DIM = (64,64,3)

CONV_FILTERS = [32,64,64, 128]
CONV_KERNEL_SIZES = [4,4,4,4]
CONV_STRIDES = [2,2,2,2]
CONV_ACTIVATIONS = ['relu','relu','relu','relu']

DENSE_SIZE = 1024

CONV_T_FILTERS = [64,64,32,3]
CONV_T_KERNEL_SIZES = [5,5,6,6]
CONV_T_STRIDES = [2,2,2,2]
CONV_T_ACTIVATIONS = ['relu','relu','relu','sigmoid']

Z_DIM = 32

BATCH_SIZE = 100
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
KL_TOLERANCE = 0.5




class Sampling(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        mu, log_var = inputs
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu), mean=0., stddev=1.)
        return mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon


class VAEModel(Model):


    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, r_loss_factor, **kwargs):
        super(VAEModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.r_loss_factor = r_loss_factor

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        def compute_kernel(x, y):
            x_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
            y_size = tf.shape(y)[0]
            dim = tf.shape(x)[1]
            tiled_x = tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, tf.stack([x_size, 1, dim])), tf.stack([1, y_size, 1]))
            tiled_y = tf.tile(tf.reshape(y, tf.stack([1, y_size, dim])), tf.stack([x_size, 1, 1]))
            return tf.exp(-tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tiled_x - tiled_y), axis=2) / tf.cast(dim, tf.float32))

        def compute_mmd(x, y):
            x_kernel = compute_kernel(x, x)
            y_kernel = compute_kernel(y, y)
            xy_kernel = compute_kernel(x, y)
            return tf.reduce_mean(x_kernel) + tf.reduce_mean(y_kernel) - 2 * tf.reduce_mean(xy_kernel)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.square(data - reconstruction), axis = [1,2,3]
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= self.r_loss_factor
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis = 1)
            kl_loss *= -0.5

            true_samples = tf.random.normal(tf.stack([BATCH_SIZE, Z_DIM]))
            loss_mmd = compute_mmd(true_samples, z)
            

            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + loss_mmd
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
            "mmd_loss": loss_mmd
        }
    
    def call(self,inputs):
        latent = self.encoder(inputs)
        return self.decoder(latent)



class VAE():
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = self._build()
        self.full_model = self.models[0]
        self.encoder = self.models[1]
        self.decoder = self.models[2]

        self.input_dim = INPUT_DIM
        self.z_dim = Z_DIM
        self.learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE
        self.kl_tolerance = KL_TOLERANCE

    def _build(self):
        vae_x = Input(shape=INPUT_DIM, name='observation_input')
        vae_c1 = Conv2D(filters = CONV_FILTERS[0], kernel_size = CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[0], strides = CONV_STRIDES[0], activation=CONV_ACTIVATIONS[0], name='conv_layer_1')(vae_x)
        vae_c2 = Conv2D(filters = CONV_FILTERS[1], kernel_size = CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[1], strides = CONV_STRIDES[1], activation=CONV_ACTIVATIONS[0], name='conv_layer_2')(vae_c1)
        vae_c3= Conv2D(filters = CONV_FILTERS[2], kernel_size = CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[2], strides = CONV_STRIDES[2], activation=CONV_ACTIVATIONS[0], name='conv_layer_3')(vae_c2)
        vae_c4= Conv2D(filters = CONV_FILTERS[3], kernel_size = CONV_KERNEL_SIZES[3], strides = CONV_STRIDES[3], activation=CONV_ACTIVATIONS[0], name='conv_layer_4')(vae_c3)

        vae_z_in = Flatten()(vae_c4)

        vae_z_mean = Dense(Z_DIM, name='mu')(vae_z_in)
        vae_z_log_var = Dense(Z_DIM, name='log_var')(vae_z_in)

        vae_z = Sampling(name='z')([vae_z_mean, vae_z_log_var])
        

        #### DECODER: 
        vae_z_input = Input(shape=(Z_DIM,), name='z_input')

        vae_dense = Dense(1024, name='dense_layer')(vae_z_input)
        vae_unflatten = Reshape((1,1,DENSE_SIZE), name='unflatten')(vae_dense)
        vae_d1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters = CONV_T_FILTERS[0], kernel_size = CONV_T_KERNEL_SIZES[0] , strides = CONV_T_STRIDES[0], activation=CONV_T_ACTIVATIONS[0], name='deconv_layer_1')(vae_unflatten)
        vae_d2 = Conv2DTranspose(filters = CONV_T_FILTERS[1], kernel_size = CONV_T_KERNEL_SIZES[1] , strides = CONV_T_STRIDES[1], activation=CONV_T_ACTIVATIONS[1], name='deconv_layer_2')(vae_d1)
        vae_d3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters = CONV_T_FILTERS[2], kernel_size = CONV_T_KERNEL_SIZES[2] , strides = CONV_T_STRIDES[2], activation=CONV_T_ACTIVATIONS[2], name='deconv_layer_3')(vae_d2)
        vae_d4 = Conv2DTranspose(filters = CONV_T_FILTERS[3], kernel_size = CONV_T_KERNEL_SIZES[3] , strides = CONV_T_STRIDES[3], activation=CONV_T_ACTIVATIONS[3], name='deconv_layer_4')(vae_d3)
        

        #### MODELS

    
        vae_encoder = Model(vae_x, [vae_z_mean, vae_z_log_var, vae_z], name = 'encoder')
        vae_decoder = Model(vae_z_input, vae_d4, name = 'decoder')

        vae_full = VAEModel(vae_encoder, vae_decoder, 10000)

        opti = Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE)
        vae_full.compile(optimizer=opti)
        
        return (vae_full,vae_encoder, vae_decoder)

    def set_weights(self, filepath):
        self.full_model.load_weights(filepath)

    def train(self, data):

        self.full_model.fit(data, data,
                shuffle=True,
                epochs=1,
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
        
    def save_weights(self, filepath):
        self.full_model.save_weights(filepath)
```

Problem:

```py
vae = VAE()
vae.set_weights(filepath)
```

throws:

> ```py
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 2200, in load_weights
>     'Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed ' ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a
> subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the
> Model first, then load the weights.
> ```

I am not sure what this means since I am not that proficient in OOP. The surprising bit is that the above code was working until it stopped working. The model is training from scratch and it saves the weights in `filepath`. But when I am loading the same weights now it is throwing the above error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of TF are you running? For a while the default saving format was hdf5, but this format cannot support subclassed models as easily, so you get this error. It may be solvable by first training it on a single batch and then loading the weights (to determine how the parts are connected, which is not saved in hdf5).

In the future I would recommend making sure that all saves are done with the TF file format though, it will save you from extra work.

Comment: I was using Tensorflow 2.3
I fixed it (well sort of) by downgrading it to Tensorflow 1.14.0

Comment: did you try doing a run on a single batch and then loading the weights? I believe this would work and you would not have to downgrade TF and lose the functionality from recent versions

Comment: I am curious why would running on a single batch help

Comment: I believe that hdf5 does not store how the layers are connected and subclasses networks can be connected outside of the sequential format so this information is unknown. Running on a single batch will then set how the variables are connected, and loading the weights should work then

Comment: Hi @alwaysmvp45, I can confirm that this works, I had the same problem. I am also using TF 2.3. But can it really be that this is the best way to load weights in TF 2.3? I only add a tiny line `model.fit(x_train[:1], y_train[:1], batch_size=1, epochs=1)` to my code before loading weights, but it still feels hacky.

Comment: @UlfAslak Unfortunately it is the best method if you are saving in hdf5 because it does not store the information you need to recreate the model. Do note that there is model.train_on_batch() which may be more efficient. I believe the best solution though is to save it as the .tf format, as this should save the connection information so you do not need to train on a single batch.

Answer (score 20):

If you set `model.built = True` prior to loading the model weights it works.

Comment: I think that is a bit of a shortcut... IMHO, after the model architecture has been specified you should build it calling build(input_shape). Then you can load the weights.

Comment: This is not the correct method and should be downvoted/removed. The layer connections are totally unknown and it is impossible to say whether the correct architecture will be run, because the model has not actually run its build function yet. It will attempt to place weights into the build, but if you use a different batch size you will have problems. Please use the TF format in the future and run on a single batch prior to loading the weights.

Answer (score 6):

i was getting same same error while loading weights via

```
model.load_weights("Detection_model.h5")
```

> ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.

solved it by building model before loading weights

```
model.build(input_shape = <INPUT_SHAPE>)
model.load_weights("Detection_model.h5")
```

ps, tensorflow Version: 2.5.0

Comment: I don't understand why it is necessary to use this build method? It works but need to understand reason behind because older version doesn't require this method to be inclueded.

Answer (score 3):

As [alwaysmvp45](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12288338/alwaysmvp45) pointed out "hdf5 does not store how the layers are connected". To make these layers be connected, another way is that you call the model to predict a zeros array with input shape (`(1,w,h,c)`) before loading weights:

```
model(np.zeros((1,w,h,c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has changed in more recent versions (I'm on 2.4). but I had to go this route:

```
# Do all the build and training 
# ...
# Save the weights
model.save('path/to/location.h5')

# delete any reference to the model
del model

# Now do the load for testing
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location.h5')
```

If I tried the other suggestions, I got warnings about the layers not being present and I had to build the same model that I did the training on. No big deal, stick it in in a function somewhere, but this works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading weights with .h5 files, you should building model first:

```
model.build(input_shape=())
model.load_weights(r'your_h5_files.h5')
```

`input_shape` should be a 4-dims tuples, if your input is 3-dims, just take the first dim with `None` like:`model.build(input_shape=(None, 224, 224, 3))`