# Load model failed in tensorflow 2.9.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load the weights of a model implemented in `tensorflow 2.9.1` but failed

I saved the model using `model.save_weights("./saved_model/model")`

and loaded the model using

```py
model = DepthEstimationModel()
model.load_weights(os.path.join("saved_model", "model"))
model.compile(optimizer, loss=cross_entropy)
model.built = True
model.summary()
```

It shows that

```
Model: "depth_estimation_model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 downscale_block (DownscaleB  multiple                 0 (unused)
 lock)                                                           
                                                                 
 downscale_block_1 (Downscal  multiple                 0 (unused)
 eBlock)                                                         
                                                                 
 downscale_block_2 (Downscal  multiple                 0 (unused)
 eBlock)                                                         
                                                                 
 downscale_block_3 (Downscal  multiple                 0 (unused)
 eBlock)                                                         
                                                                 
 bottle_neck_block (BottleNe  multiple                 0 (unused)
 ckBlock)                                                        
                                                                 
 upscale_block (UpscaleBlock  multiple                 0 (unused)
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 upscale_block_1 (UpscaleBlo  multiple                 0 (unused)
 ck)                                                             
                                                                 
 upscale_block_2 (UpscaleBlo  multiple                 0 (unused)
 ck)                                                             
                                                                 
 upscale_block_3 (UpscaleBlo  multiple                 0 (unused)
 ck)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_18 (Conv2D)          multiple                  0 (unused)
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 2
```

Which indicates the params are not loaded correctly.

If `model.built = True` is removed, it outputs:

```
This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling the model on a batch of data.
```

Reference: [Tensorflow 2.0 ValueError while Loading weights from .h5 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658086/tensorflow-2-0-valueerror-while-loading-weights-from-h5-file)

Comment: Have you tried loading the weights using the path in the same way as you saved the weights? Also, have you tried to run model.build() or evaluate the model (after compilation) using a valuation dataset?

Comment: @LucaKnaack using `model.evaluate()` actually worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before loading the weights you have to compile your model, then you have to load weights. For example

```
model.compile(optimizer, loss=cross_entropy)
model.load_weights(os.path.join("saved_model", "model"))
```

Then you will not face that error.Thank You.